# Facebook og:url ignored in favour of a Facebook hosted page about the og entity

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to implement the Like button on my pages.

Those pages represent the review page for a product. When a user Likes the page, it shows up in Facebook (not as a link, but as liking an entity), however when you click on the entity in Facebook it links through to a facebook.com hosted page representing the page. I want the user to be redirected to the og:url page?

This happens for example when you Like an artist page on Grroveshar: http://grooveshark.com/#!/artist/Elbow/4795

I am clearly "doing it wrong".

I am using the following markup to include the SDK. MYAPPID is included by the code generator Facebook provides so I assume it is required.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MYAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then my code to render the Like button.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

And finally my og tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My product" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://site.com/product_1/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://site.com/image1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My-Site-Name.com" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="MYFACEBOOKID" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MYAPPID" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding the data-href parameter to the fb-like div? Just to make sure it’s not liking another URL than that which you’ve intended.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks - I tried it but the same result. I get a facebook.com/Pages/My_Product result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing the Admin Page for that URL with the URL itself, but i could be wrong because the admin page has a message at the top explaining this which looks like this:
[image: Admin page message]

Only the admins will see the on-Facebook admin page, and other users will be brought back to the `og:url` value defined on the URL which was liked. If you're not specifying a data-href parameter in the HTML5 Like plugin, this will be the current page or whatever the `og:url` value is on the current page's meta tags

Check what [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) says for the URL you're trying to like and make sure the tags are being read correctly

Comment: Ha - no I was actually being that stupid. The yellow box was a little way down the page and I missed it. I am used to having the Admin interface for page administration so I assumed it was just a header on top of what a regular user would see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the grooveshark example is the fact they are using `#!` urls. If you wereto like `http://grooveshark.com/artist/Elbow/4795` instead it would work correctly. If you are using such URL patterns than you will run into problems, and you would need to override the like button to hit the url without it.